# How can I prove that $g(\zeta)\in\mathbb R\implies g(\zeta)=h(\zeta+\bar\zeta)$

Tags: polynomials

How can I prove that if $g(X)\in \mathbb Q[X]$ and $\zeta\in\mathbb C\backslash \mathbb R$, therefore $$g(\zeta)\in\mathbb R\implies g(\zeta)=h(\zeta+\bar\zeta)$$ for a certain polynomial $h(X)\in\mathbb Q[X]$ ?

Let $$g(X)=a_0+a_1X+...+a_nX^n,$$
I know that $$g(\zeta)\in\mathbb R\implies g(\zeta)=\overline{g(\zeta)}\underset{a_i\in\mathbb Q}{=}g(\bar\zeta)$$

therefore $$a_1(\zeta-\bar\zeta)+a_2(\zeta^2-\bar\zeta^2)+...+a_n(\zeta^n-\bar\zeta^n)=0,$$
and thus $$\Im(\zeta^k-\bar\zeta^k)=0,$$
for all $k$, but I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 5):

The claim seems false as currently stated. Consider for example 
$g(X)=X^2, \zeta=i\sqrt[4]{7}$. Then $g(\zeta)=-\sqrt{7}\in{\mathbb R}$,
but $g(\zeta)$ can never equal $h(\zeta+\bar{\zeta})$ for any 
$h\in{\mathbb Q}[X]$ (because $g(\zeta)$ is irrational and
$h(\zeta+\bar{\zeta})$ is rational, indeed $\zeta+\bar{\zeta}=0$).

Comment: This explains why I could not prove the claim. :-) But it seems that I can prove it provided $\zeta\bar\zeta\in\Bbb Q$.

Comment: So it mean that it's wrong to say that: "$g(\zeta)=\overline{g(\zeta)}$ if and only if $\zeta$ and $\bar\zeta$ appear with the same coefficient in $g$, i.e. $g$ is a polynomial in $\zeta+\bar\zeta$ ? " Because it's what the corrector wrote on my last exams.

Comment: @idm perhaps you could scan the relevant page on your last exam and upload it here, so that we might be able to explain it better to you

Answer (score 1):

In the original contest question it was assumed that $|\zeta|=1$.

The question was asked in the KöMaL Magazine. You can find the solution at
http://www.komal.hu/verseny/feladat.cgi?a=feladat&f=A498&l=en

Answer (score 0):

I present my ideas for the case $\zeta\bar\zeta\in\Bbb Q$, which is more general than $\zeta\bar\zeta=|\zeta|^2=1$.

It seems the following.

Since $g(\zeta)=g(\bar\zeta)$, $g(\zeta)+g(\bar\zeta)=2g(\zeta)\in\Bbb R$. So $$2a_0+a_1(\zeta+\bar\zeta)+a_2(\zeta^2+\bar\zeta^2)+...+a_n(\zeta^n+\bar\zeta^n)\in \Bbb R.$$

Now it rests to show that $\zeta^k+\bar\zeta^k$ is a polynomial with rational coefficiemts of $\zeta+\bar\zeta$ for each $k$, that can be done inductively, because $\zeta^0+\bar\zeta^0=2$, $\zeta^1+\bar\zeta^1=\zeta+\bar\zeta$ and  $$\zeta^{k+1}+\bar\zeta^{k+1}=(\zeta^{k}+\bar\zeta^{k})(\zeta+\bar\zeta)-\zeta\bar\zeta(\zeta^{k-1}+\bar\zeta^{k-1})$$ for each $k\ge 1$.